# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: apex

```
 List<AggregateResult> List1 = [select SUM(DScore__c), SUM(PScore__c), SUM(NScore__c) from Employee__c where Account =: currentRecordId];
    if(List1.size() > 0) {
        double D = Double.valueOf(List1[0].get('expr0'));
        double P = Double.valueOf(List1 [0].get('expr2'));

        double gScore = ((P*100)/123) - ((D*100)/123);
        //Some calculation        }
    List<AggregateResult> lst = [SELECT count(Claim__c) FROM Model__c Where  Account =: currentRecordId ];
            Double val=0;
    for(AggregateResult ar:lst)
    {
        val = val + Double.valueOf(ar.get('expr0'));
    }
    List<AggregateResult> count = [SELECT count(Name) FROM Employee__c];

    Double cntval=0;
    for(AggregateResult ar:count)
    {
        cntval = cntval + Double.valueOf(ar.get('expr0'));
    }
    dlProfile= String.valueOf(val/cntval);
```

I am getting the error for tis section of the code. What could be the reason possibly?

Comment: Which line, specifically, does the exception throw from?

Comment: you calculating sum for single element in for loop. Try to use model: integer amt = [select count() from opportunity];

Comment: If source for aggregate result is not defined, you will get NullPointer

Comment: @sfdcfox- Sorry for asking , but how do I understand that ? I can see <init>: line 56, column 1 at the bottom . Does that indicate the line number of the error?

Comment: Which one of those is line 56?

Answer (score 0):

In case when you have all aggregated fields as not defined, you'll get AggregateResult as null.
If P is null, next line may throw nullpoiner:

```
double gScore = ((P*100)/123) - ((D*100)/123);
```

You can add null checks before calculations, or add where clause to your query:

```
List<AggregateResult> List1 = [select SUM(DScore__c), from Employee__c where DScore__c <> Null];
if(List1.size() > 0) {
```

Later if cntval variable remains 0, you will get MathException.